# Why PHP rename() is deleting files?

Tags: php, rename, file-rename

I can't identify whats wrong with my code.
This line of code is deleting the files instead of renaming them.

```
for($i=0;$i<(7-$n);$i++){   
    rename($location."/".($last-$i).".txt", $location."/".($last-$i-$n).".txt");
    rename($location."/".($last-$i).".bmp", $location."/".($last-$i-$n).".bmp");            
}
```

I already echoed both source and destination filenames and it looks correct to me.
I'm doing the same "variable salad" with the unlink() function and it behaves as expected.
I tried to make my own rename() funcion:

```
function myRename($old, $new){
  $content = printFile($old); //this function returns the content of a file.
  unlink($old);
  $file = fopen($new, "w");
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
}
```

The same error occurs. All renamed files ends being deleted.
That makes me think there is a dumb error in the "variable salad" I made.
But I can't figure out what is. The echoed result looks correct to me.
PHP doesn't give me any Warnings related to the ploblem.

Echoed results:

Source: "data/directory_exemple/47.txt" 
Destination: "data/directory_exemple/46.txt"

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Looks like just one of the files gets renamed. The rest is deleted.
Maybe it's a logic error.

Comment: Do the user who runs the php script has write access to the folder you're trying to rename the files in?

Comment: Erm, you are attempting to rename `47.txt` to `46.txt` but surely `46.txt` already exists

Comment: @JonathanKortleven If they did not, then surely nothing would change at all

Comment: Try echo-ing your rename calls after the call to `rename()` and see if the flow makes sense. Like `echo "rename(".$location."/".($last-$i).".txt", $location."/".($last-$i-$n).".txt");";<br>` You might find that your adding poo croutons to your salad when you wanted parmesan-garlic flavored.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Shame on me! I think you are correct!
I swear I thought of that. But I was so desperate to finish this project as soon as possible that I kept insisting on trying to find mistakes where it didn't exist. Thanks for helping me! It indeed was a dumb error as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

You below function works properly

```
function myRename($old, $new){
  $content = printFile($old); //this function returns the content of a file.
  unlink($old);
  $file = fopen($new, "w");
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
}
```

I have tested your `myRename()` function with sample file, it renames.

Make sure that you have correct path, getting content from `printFile()`  and write permission

Comment: Not saying that this is wrong, but why would that matter as long as the OP reads the contents of the old file before it gets unlinked, which is the case?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, you are right . It keeps content of file even we unlink first. Edited my answer

Comment: This has actually now gone from being an answer to being a comment. Posting the OP's original code with "it works" with a couple of suggestions on what to check isn't really a good answer.